# Ember-data building relationships without ids

Tags: ember-data

I'm trying to build an Ember application with a MongoDB backend. Ember-data now supports embedded objects which makes it really easy and great to be able to pull the objects right out of the nested document.

My problem is in figuring out how to relate objects to each other.

Lets look at an example of a class room with students and assignments.

```
{
  students: [
    { name: 'Billy' },
    { name: 'Joe' }
  ],
  assignments: [
    { name: 'HW1', score: 70, student_name: 'Billy' },
    { name: 'HW2', score: 80, student_name: 'Billy' },
    { name: 'HW1', score: 60, student_name: 'Joe' },
    { name: 'HW2', score: 75, student_name: 'Joe' }
  ]
}
```

How would I build a relationship for the `student` so that I could pull back all of their `assignments`?

Related, I'm trying to figure out how to relate objects that are nested inside each other. I created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agarat/9/edit) trying to build a relationship between nested objects (going up the tree rather than just down) but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the repo below to guide you on how to do embedded association. Though they are not using mongodb, the important thing is on the ember-data side, they are doing embedded association.

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/controllers/contact_edit_controller.js

Note that here App.PhoneNumber is embedded in App.Contact. But it should give you an idea on how to go abut resolving yours.

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  notes: DS.attr('string'),
  phoneNumbers: DS.hasMany('App.PhoneNumber'),
});

App.PhoneNumber = DS.Model.extend({
  number: DS.attr('string'),
  contact: DS.belongsTo('App.Contact')
});
```

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/store.js

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  bulkCommit: false
});

App.Adapter.map('App.Contact', {
  phoneNumbers: {embedded: 'always'}
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: App.Adapter.create()
});
```

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/controllers/contact_edit_controller.js

```
App.ContactEditController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
 needs: ['contact'],

 startEditing: function() {
   // add the contact and its associated phone numbers to a local transaction
   var contact = this.get('content');
   var transaction = contact.get('store').transaction();
   transaction.add(contact);
   contact.get('phoneNumbers').forEach(function(phoneNumber) {
   transaction.add(phoneNumber);
 });
   this.transaction = transaction;
  },

  save: function() {
   this.transaction.commit();
  },

  addPhoneNumber: function() {
    this.get('content.phoneNumbers').createRecord();
  },

});
```

Comment: I'll have to check it out closer, but do you know if, once you have a phoneNumber if you are able to reference the contact? That backwards relationship is the part giving me a hard time.

Comment: The App.Adapter.map line gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined...` I guess this has changed in ember1.0 ?

Comment: In the current version. ember-data, things have changed much and some things in this code no longer apply. the **RestAdapter, no longer needs to be declare as it is done automatically but if you are using the **fixtureAdapter in jsfiddle, that should be declared. Also you no longer define **App.Store** except if you want to extend something. **Embedding**, relationships is temporarily removed but will be re-added in future.  With **rails** and **emberjs**, use the **activemodeladapter** that comes bundled with ember-data. defining **relationship** has changed. See: **http://bit.ly/14Pl9Av**